# Posting JSON to DocumentDB through REST API

Tags: c#, json, azure, restsharp, azure-cosmosdb

Just made the transition from Sql Server to Microsoft's DocumentDB service, and I am struggling to create a document through their REST API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn803948.aspx). I've tried with RestSharp and WebClient with no luck. I'm sure it's probably a simple oversight. The following code has an Account object with only the required property (id) ...just for the sake of testing. Any help would be great.

```
public class Account
{
    public string id { get; set; }

}

////////////////////////////////////

  Account customerAcc = new Account
    {
        id = "test1"

    };

////////////////////////////////////////////

 var baseUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_documentDB_endpoint");
 var primary_key = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_documentDB_primary_key");
 var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
 var data = "type=master&ver=1.0&sig=" + primary_key;

 RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
 restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
 restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", data);
 restRequest.AddHeader("x-ms-date",now.ToUniversalTime().ToString());
 restRequest.AddBody(customerAcc);

 IRestResponse irestResponse = client.Execute(restRequest);


 ///////////////////////////////////// OR WITH SYSTEM.NET.WEBCLIENT
  string result = "";
  using (var newClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            newClient.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            newClient.Headers["Authorization"] = data;
            newClient.Headers["x-ms-date"] = now.ToUniversalTime().ToString();
            result = newClient.UploadString(baseUrl, "POST", "{\"id\":\"test1\"}");
        }
```

The calls are getting authorized, but continue to get a 400 Status Code (BAD REQUEST) response. I've tried serializing the object, and replacing the restRequest.AddBody with restRequest.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8",json,ParameterType.RequestBody). This didn't have any impact.

Comment: The problem isn't the client library, it's the request. It doesn't help to change clients when the request remains broken. First try to create a valid HTTP request with a tool like Postman or curl, then try to   Why did you try WebClient instead of HttpClient anyway, or DocumentDB's .NET library?

Comment: Use Fiddler to see what exactly is sent to the service and compare it to the documentation's [request samples]. The docs say that a 400 means that the  Json body is malformed but you may find other headers that are missing

Comment: @Panagiotis - Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try Fiddler. Regarding the code, I just showed both client versions I tried but didn't run them together. I prefer RestSharp but tried WebClient quickly to see if anything changed. I'm not using the .NET library because I only need a few quick calls in a handler file, and unfortunately have had issues with all the async requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use Azure DocumentDB in a .NET application - you may find it easier to simply use the [.NET SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/).

Assuming you'd really like to get the REST API working... taking a brief glance, I see a few things that need to be changed:

1.) The auth key looks off.

```
 var primary_key = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_documentDB_primary_key");
 // ...
 var data = "type=master&ver=1.0&sig=" + primary_key;
 // ...
 restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", data);
```

Rather than passing in a master key, you will need to produce a hash signature. You can find [documentation on auth here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783368.aspx)

2.) The URI that you sending a POST request to looks a bit off.

```
var baseUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_documentDB_endpoint");
// ...
result = newClient.UploadString(baseUrl, "POST", "{\"id\":\"test1\"}");
```

You will need to construct the URI based on the resource you are trying to operate on. For example, the URI for creating a document should look something like:

```
https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{_rid-db}/colls/{_rid-col}/docs
```